# Django Python "TypeError: view must be callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()" with urls

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-urls

I'm getting a "TypeError: view must be callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()" for the subscribe url below for Weather_App/urls.py

```
import signupform.urls
import signupform.views as views

app_name = "Weather_App"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    url(r'^subscribe/', signupform.urls, name='signup'),
]
```

In my other urls file signupform/urls.py, I had a similar issue but fixed it using a views import

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views as Weather_App_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', Weather_App_views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'confirm/$', Weather_App_views.confirm, name='confirm'),
]
```

Views looks like

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import *
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import IntegrityError

from .models import WeatherSubscription

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'signupform/index.html', {'location_set':WeatherSubscription.city_choices})

def confirm(request):
    ws = WeatherSubscription(email=request.POST['email_input'], location=request.POST['location_input'])
    render_kwargs = {}
    try:
        ws.clean_fields()
        ws.save()
    except ValidationError as e:
        render_kwargs['invalid_message'] = 'Email not in a standard form.'
    except IntegrityError as e:
        render_kwargs['invalid_message'] = 'Email already subscribed.'

    return render(request, 'signupform/confirm.html', render_kwargs)
```

Models just has a WeatherSubscription function

And my structure is
signedupform
-**init**
-apps
-models
-settings
-urls
-views
Weather_App
-**init**
-settings
-urls
-wsgi

Comment: What is your Django version?

Comment: I have the newest versions of Python 3 and Django right now

Answer (score 2):

you need to import the url file from your app to the main app for instance if you want to import signupform.urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url , include
from . import views as Weather_App_vie

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    url(r'^subscribe/',include('signupform.urls'), name='signup'),
]
```

Comment: my example only works if your app name is called signupform and you are trying to import urls.py inside your app

Comment: !! It looks like that worked!! I'm so confused as to why include works here and didn't work originally in my other file, but thank you!

Comment: it's easy , you user include to import urls.py from other apps usually to the main project urls.py , so if you created any new app you have to import views to the main project urls.py and use,but if you want to use a separate url.py file for your app you have to include it in your main project app in you case Weather_App is the main project app so if you want the second urls.py file to work you have to include it

Comment: It looks like it works without the import, I just really needed the include part. I'll slowly figure it out though, thanks again!